# Cancellation of form submission link in email, Google forms and Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

For an approval workflow, I am using standard Google Forms and scripts behind the Google sheets to get approval from managers.

Is it possible to click "Cancel" link in the email and be redirected to another static webpage, also the status being updated to the manager that the request has been cancelled?

It is something similar to this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eduG0XZ9mDs) but without publishing it as a service.

Comment: Still haven't found solution to above query but found alternative, create new cancellation form and send a link in email to user.